# decode audio data on IOS safari (iphone 8 or lower) not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-audio-api

I'm making a music composer and i need to decode audio files to then use them with the web audio API, everything works as expected with all browsers except some old versions of safari on ios.

I managed to narrow down the error to one function but i have no idea what could be causing it, the error is:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.decodeAudioData(e,n
```

(i'm using react, this is the built version, i dont have an iOS device so i have to use browserstack instead)
the code is:

```js
        const requests = this.layout.map(e => {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                fetch(e.url)
                    .then(result => result.arrayBuffer())
                    .then(buffer => {
                        audioContext.decodeAudioData(buffer, resolve, () => {
                            //iOS doesn't have the promise based decodeAudioData
                            resolve(emptyBuffer)
                        })
                    }).catch(e => {
                        console.error(e) //error is logged here
                        resolve(emptyBuffer)
                    })
            })
        })
```

I tried logging every variable but they are all valid.